# Windows 10 Toaster Notifications: more than 1 at a time?

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I have a basic Node application that occasionally shows toast notifications using gulp-notify.  If two or three get sent within a brief period of time, the first shows for the full five seconds, then it hides while the second shows for the full 5 seconds, and so on.  So if there are three within a brief period, the third won't show for a full 10 seconds.

Is it possible to have the 2nd, 3rd...Nth toast notification just start stacking vertically on top of / on the bottom of the prior one?  That was the behavior of Windows 8.1; is there a way to get Windows 10 to behave the same?  I've looked through the notifications settings and I can't find anything at all.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: @Stephen - nope, sorry

Comment: Alright, odd that windows doesn't give the option...oh well we can always use growl